# Как воспользоваться $wpdb и работать с БД в своем file.php

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

```
function SetPostViews(postId) {
   global $wpdb;
   $query="SELECT `downloadsCount` FROM `wp_posts` WHERE `ID`=";
   $query.=postId;
   $downloadsCount = $wpdb->get_var($query);    
   $query="UPDATE `wp_posts` SET `downloadsCount` =";
   $query.=++$downloadsCount;
   $query.=" WHERE `ID`=";
   $query.=postId;
   $wpdb->query($query);
   $result = "<p class ='downloads'>Загрузок: " . $downloadsCount . "</p>";
   return $result;
}
```

Подскажите, как этим воспользоваться в file.php, добавленном в папку с темой.
Как подключить?

Answer (score 0):

Копируете содержимое в ваш file.php, и подключаете его в functions.php.